# How to use MDSpinner during function call in python kivy

Tags: python, kivy

I have a lengthy function that requires some time to be called, I want to use MDSpinner before the function is called and let it stop once the function is completely done, the thing is the screen is getting bugged once the function is called, I would like to know how to force the window to add the MDSpinner so it can pass all the widgets and then how can I remove it, when Iam using MDSpinner.active... all will lag untill the function is completely called!

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `Clock.schedule_once()` to schedule your long process to the next frame. Basically, kivy won't show your spinner until the whole process is done. You can't even use your app while it's doing the process. It basically looks like `freeze`. There are two methods you can do. First, you can use `threading` to run the long process in another thread and show spinner using the main thread. You can also use `Clock.schedule_once` to postpone your process to the next frame. You can check more details [here](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.clock.html)